# Split Javascript IP Address String into Multiple Lines, Use that Variable with Three js TextGeometry

Tags: javascript, string, text, split

I'm having a problem getting three.js TextGeometry to properly display a split up string.

I'm grabbing the myip variable from a remote source:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://l2.io/ip.js?var=myip"></script>
```

Then splitting it up at the periods and adding a space so each group of numbers displays on a new line:

```
<script>
var formattedString = myip.split('.').join('\n');

alert(formattedString);

var text3d = new THREE.TextGeometry( formattedString, {

                size: 1,
                height: 1,
                curveSegments: 10,
                font: "helvetiker"

            });
</script>
```

The alert displays the split up IP address properly, but the TextGeometry output displays it with question marks.

You can see how it's displaying [here](http://jonchambers.net/ipdeath/obj.html)

How can I get TextGeometry to display the split up string?

Thanks!

Comment: Side note: `var formattedString = myip.split('.').join('\n');` is probably more efficiently written `var formattedString = myip.replace(/\./g, '\n');` (not that it's really likely to matter).

Comment: Hah, classic: [It varies](http://jsperf.com/split-join-vs-replace-again) (but again is unlikely to matter).

Comment: thanks for the info/suggestions @T.J.Crowder I think i'll just display each of the array items as individual geometries like in the post you linked to...seems to be the most straight forward.